# Form submission not received because all checkboxes not checked

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have set-up a Sign Up form where the user has to check which service they would like, my HTML looks like this:

```
<label><input name="serviceopt1" type="checkbox" id="serviceopt1" value="1"> IT Services</label>
<label><input name="serviceopt2" type="checkbox" id="serviceopt2" value="1"> Catering Services</label>
<label><input name="serviceopt3" type="checkbox" id="serviceopt3" value="1"> PAT Testing</label>
<label><input name="serviceopt4" type="checkbox" id="serviceopt4" value="1"> Building Services</label>
```

Then I have set my ajaxform as follows where if non are selected then it will ask you to check the first checkbox:

```
var serviceopt1 = $("input[name=serviceopt1]:checked").val();
var serviceopt2 = $("input[name=serviceopt2]:checked").val();
var serviceopt3 = $("input[name=serviceopt3]:checked").val();
var serviceopt4 = $("input[name=serviceopt4]:checked").val();

if (serviceopt1 == "") {
    $("input:checkbox[name=serviceopt1]").val();
    $("input:checkbox[name=serviceopt1]").parent("label").css({color:"#b72a18"});
      return false;
    }
```

The issue I am having is if some of the following check boxes are unchecked they go through as undefined which stops the email confirmation coming through.

So how do I get around this so if they are checked they go through with a value of 1 and if they are unchecked the value is just 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you're looking for but following code might help you:

If you just want to set `1` where checkbox is checked and `0` where checkbox is no checked, just do this

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change",function(){
    $("input:checkbox").each(function(i,elem){
        this.checked ? this.value = 1 : this.value = 0
    });
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7mw5vt3/)

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much for your answer!

Comment: @Craig Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Ok regarding your ***The issue I am having is if some of the following check boxes are unchecked they go through as undefined which stops the email confirmation coming through*** I would like to correct some of the things here.

When you write below line

```
var serviceopt1 = $("input[name=serviceopt1]:checked").val();
```

The `serviceop1` will always be undefined if you haven't `checked` the checkbox because the above line `$("input[name=serviceopt1]:checked")` will check if the `checkbox` is checked and then gets its value. So while storing values in variables you just do

```
var serviceopt1 = $('input[name="serviceopt1"]').val();
```

This will get the value of `input checkbox` with `name = serviceopt1`. Same goes with other `checkboxes` too.

Now regarding changing the `value` you could use @DhavalMarthak's approach which changes `checkboxes` value and there will be value always in your `variables`

To perform validation you can do as below so that at least one `checkbox` is `checked`

```
if (serviceopt1 == "0" && serviceopt2=="0" && serviceopt3="0" && serviceopt4=="0" ) 
{
    //none of them are checked
    $.each($('input:checkbox[name^="serviceopt"]'),function(){
        $(this).parent("label").css({color:"#b72a18"}); //add css to all labels of checkbox since none of them are checked
        return false;
   }
}
```

> **I assume here that you need only one `checkbox` to be `checked`**